How can I destroy / delete an option?
Invalid return …

The local variable ‘Option’ might still contain a value. The value does not have the ‘drop’ ability and must be consumed before the function returns

Move compiler failed…
How to destroy / delete an option, whose name is weaponOption?
if(option::is_some(&weaponOption)) {
    let weapon = option::extract(&mut weaponOption);
    //let Weapon { id, damage: _} = weapon; object::delete(id);
    transfer::transfer(weapon, sender);
}else{
    option::destroy_none(weaponOption);
};


You can use option::destroy_some and option::destroy_none
if(option::is_some(&weaponOption)) {
    let weapon = option::destroy_some(weaponOption);
    //let Weapon { id, damage: _} = weapon;
    //object::delete(id);
    transfer::transfer(weapon, sender);
}else{
    option::destroy_none(weaponOption);
};

reference

the option module in Sui is auto imported. not sure about Aptos. reference added
